# Woocommerce - Abrir página do produto somente se o usuário estiver logado

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Boa tarde, preciso de um método que perceba se o usuário está logado ou não para ter acesso a página de detalhes do produto.

Estou usando um Woocommerce (Storefront) para gerenciar um site de produtos, e gostaria que o usuário consiga ver os produtos na Home, mas ao clicar no botão para entrar e ver os detalhes do produto seja feita uma verificação de registro/login e só consiga ver os detalhes do produto caso esteja logado, caso contrário seja redirecionado para página de registro/login.

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Bem complicado... as configurações de segurança de um post (ou produto) restringem ele totalmente. Ou seja, não aparece nem na tela principal. Já procurou algum _plugin_ de segurança?

Comment: Conheço alguns plugins sim, mas nenhum atendeu ao que eu quero. Vou testar esses 2 que o @chun recomendou e retorno para dizer se funcionou e se resolvi o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe utilizada para mostrar algo apenas se o usuário estiver *logado* é:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ... } ?>
```

> Referência: [Function Reference/is user logged in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Tens aqui também estes dois plugins, que fazem exatamente esse trabalho:

[Page Restrict](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/screenshots/)
[WordPress Access Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-access-control/)

Comment: Vou testar os plugins ou mexer no PHP @chun e retorno dizendo se deu certo.